# New list generated from the sum of elements taken from two lists

Tags: list-manipulation

I have been using mathematica for a while, but I have problem wrapping my head around list manipulation functions. I would appreciate any suggestions. Here is what I want to do.

ListV is a list of vectors:

```
ListV= {{x1,y1,z1},{x2,y2,z2},...}= {V1,V2,...}
```

ListU is also a list of vectors :

```
ListU={{a1,b1,c1},{a2,b2,c2},...}= {U1,U2,...}
```

ListU and ListV may have unequal lengths.

I want to make a new list (ListUV) which would contain all the new positions generated by the sum of all vectors in ListU and ListV. Mathematically, that would be

> ListUV= {V1+U1, V2+U1, ..., V2+U1, V2+U2, ... }.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Is it what you want? `Flatten[Outer[Plus, ListV, ListU], 1]`

Comment: You say `V2+U1, ... V2+U1, V2+U2`. Do you mean `V2+U1, ... V3+U1, V3+U2` ?

Comment: 'Partition[Flatten[Outer[Plus, UnitCellPositions, LatticePositions, 1]], 3]' does exactly what I need. Thank you Yi Wang for the solution.

Comment: Thank you PlatoManiac for edited the formatting.

Comment: @YiWang Please consider posting an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Two lists were created using only letters

```
listV = {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}}
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a & b & c \\
>  d & e & f \\
>  g & h & i \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
listU = {{j, k, l}, {m, n, o}, {p, q, r}}
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  j & k & l \\
>  m & n & o \\
>  p & q & r \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

With this command it is possible to create all the possibilities of sum of vectors ([Modified](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42546/new-list-generated-from-the-sum-of-elements-taken-from-two-lists/133505#comment127227_42546))

```
allVectors = Flatten[Outer[Plus, listV, listU], 2]
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  a+j & a+k & a+l \\
>  a+m & a+n & a+o \\
>  a+p & a+q & a+r \\
>  b+j & b+k & b+l \\
>  b+m & b+n & b+o \\
>  b+p & b+q & b+r \\
>  c+j & c+k & c+l \\
>  c+m & c+n & c+o \\
>  c+p & c+q & c+r \\
>  d+j & d+k & d+l \\
>  d+m & d+n & d+o \\
>  d+p & d+q & d+r \\
>  e+j & e+k & e+l \\
>  e+m & e+n & e+o \\
>  e+p & e+q & e+r \\
>  f+j & f+k & f+l \\
>  f+m & f+n & f+o \\
>  f+p & f+q & f+r \\
>  g+j & g+k & g+l \\
>  g+m & g+n & g+o \\
>  g+p & g+q & g+r \\
>  h+j & h+k & h+l \\
>  h+m & h+n & h+o \\
>  h+p & h+q & h+r \\
>  i+j & i+k & i+l \\
>  i+m & i+n & i+o \\
>  i+p & i+q & i+r \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Now the same previous information applying values ​​to the vectors

```
numericListV = {{1, 2, 0}, {0, 2, 4}, {5, 8, 10}}
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 2 & 0 \\
>  0 & 2 & 4 \\
>  5 & 8 & 10 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
Graphics3D[{Red,
```

MapThread[Arrow, {{{0, 0, 0}, #}} & /@ numericListV // Transpose]}]

> [image: Im1]

```
numericListU = {{1, 4, 5}, {3, 5, 7}, {8, 8, 9}}
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  1 & 4 & 5 \\
>  3 & 5 & 7 \\
>  8 & 8 & 9 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
Graphics3D[{Blue,
```

MapThread[Arrow, {{{0, 0, 0}, #}} & /@ numericListU // Transpose]}]

> [image: Im2]

```
allVectorsNumeric =
```

Flatten[Outer[Plus, numericListV, numericListU], 2]

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{ccc}
>  2 & 5 & 6 \\
>  4 & 6 & 8 \\
>  9 & 9 & 10 \\
>  3 & 6 & 7 \\
>  5 & 7 & 9 \\
>  10 & 10 & 11 \\
>  1 & 4 & 5 \\
>  3 & 5 & 7 \\
>  8 & 8 & 9 \\
>  1 & 4 & 5 \\
>  3 & 5 & 7 \\
>  8 & 8 & 9 \\
>  3 & 6 & 7 \\
>  5 & 7 & 9 \\
>  10 & 10 & 11 \\
>  5 & 8 & 9 \\
>  7 & 9 & 11 \\
>  12 & 12 & 13 \\
>  6 & 9 & 10 \\
>  8 & 10 & 12 \\
>  13 & 13 & 14 \\
>  9 & 12 & 13 \\
>  11 & 13 & 15 \\
>  16 & 16 & 17 \\
>  11 & 14 & 15 \\
>  13 & 15 & 17 \\
>  18 & 18 & 19 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

```
Graphics3D[{Green,
```

MapThread[
   Arrow, {{{0, 0, 0}, #}} & /@ allVectorsNumeric // Transpose]}]

> [image]